# Plot NetworkX Graph from Adjacency Matrix in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, networkx

I have been battling with this problem for a little bit now, I know this is very simple - but I have little experience with Python or NetworkX. My question is very simple, I am trying to plot a large dataset (about 200 rows/columns) of a matrix that looks like this. The first row and first column are identical.

```
  A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
A,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
B,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
C,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
```

It just a matrix showing how people are connected, and ***all I want is to import and plot this csv file, with it's corresponding labels in NetworkX.***

I have this file (`people.cs`v), and looking at previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755927/reading-a-networkx-graph-from-a-csv-file-with-row-and-column-header), it seems the best way to do this is by putting the data in an array with numpy.

There seems to be a problem with this:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

mydata = genfromtxt('mouse.csv', delimiter=',')
```

I get the following output:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1272, in genfromtxt
  fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 145, in open
  return ds.open(path, mode)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 472, in open
  found = self._findfile(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 323, in _findfile
  if self.exists(name):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 417, in exists
  from urllib2 import urlopen
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
  import httplib
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 69, in <module>
  from array import array
      File "/Users/Plosslab/Documents/PythonStuff/array.py", line 4, in <module>
      NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I made a small csv called mycsv.csv  that has the following:

```
,a,b,c,d
a,0,1,0,1
b,1,0,1,0
c,0,1,0,1
d,1,0,1,0
```

You don't have a ',' as the first character on the first row, but instead you have a space, so if this is an error on my part let me know.  The general idea will be the same.  Read in the csv as such:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np
mydata = genfromtxt('mycsv.csv', delimiter=',')
print(mydata)
print(type(mydata))
```

This prints:

```
[[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan   0.   1.   0.   1.]
 [ nan   1.   0.   1.   0.]
 [ nan   0.   1.   0.   1.]
 [ nan   1.   0.   1.   0.]]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now that we have the csv read in as a numpy array we need to extract just the adjacency matrix:

```
adjacency = mydata[1:,1:]
print(adjacency)
```

This prints:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

You can just slice your numpy array as needed if my small example isn't exactly as yours.

To plot the graph you will need to import matplotlib and networkx:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def show_graph_with_labels(adjacency_matrix, mylabels):
    rows, cols = np.where(adjacency_matrix == 1)
    edges = zip(rows.tolist(), cols.tolist())
    gr = nx.Graph()
    gr.add_edges_from(edges)
    nx.draw(gr, node_size=500, labels=mylabels, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()

show_graph_with_labels(adjacency, make_label_dict(get_labels('mycsv.csv')))
```

Here's a short [tutorial](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating-network-graphs-with-python) on graphs with python.

[image: graph from csv]

Comment: This is very helpful, but it is imperative that the nodes are labelled, whereas genfromtxt seems to remove that part.

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  Are the letters your labels?  If you want to use something other than the row / col number as your labels you can add custom labels: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/labels_and_colors.html

Comment: I finally ran this code, I get a slew of errors:

 ` File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1272, in genfromtxt
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))

NameError: name 'array' is not defined`

Comment: Saying that you got errors is not a helpful comment. What errors did you get? And can you address my previous question regarding what labels you are expecting?

Comment: Ok I will post them into the question.

Comment: Yes, the letters are my labels.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, no network errors. I am going to take your recommendation to plot the actual labels (A,B,C,D etc...) into the graph.

Comment: I'll edit so you can add your own labels (let's assume they are the letters A, B, C..., from the csv)

Comment: @Workhorse Also if you feel this answers your question would you please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: It seems that if there are no edges to some node, this node will not appear in the graph using this method.

Comment: Where do `make_label_dict()` and `get_labels()` come from? Are they evident to everyone except myself?

Answer (score 19):

This can be done easily by using `pandas` and `networkx`.

For example, I have created a small `csv` file called `test.csv` as

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
A,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
B,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
C,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
D,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0
E,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
F,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
G,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
H,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0
I,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
J,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
K,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0
```

You can read this csv file and create graph as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
input_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
G = nx.DiGraph(input_data.values)
```

For plotting this graph use

```
nx.draw(G)
```

You would be getting a plot something similar to this.

[image: Output of <code>nx.draw(G)</code>]

Comment: Is it not necessary to start the 1st row with comma to indicate that the 1st cell is empty?

Answer (score 2):

This is identical to [Scott's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29574114/165753) but handles correctly nodes without edges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def show_graph_with_labels(adjacency_matrix, mylabels):
    rows, cols = np.where(adjacency_matrix == 1)
    edges = zip(rows.tolist(), cols.tolist())
    gr = nx.Graph()
    all_rows = range(0, adjacency_matrix.shape[0])
    for n in all_rows:
        gr.add_node(n)
    gr.add_edges_from(edges)
    nx.draw(gr, node_size=900, labels=mylabels, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```