# How to create a 4 or 8 connected adjacency matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, adjacency-matrix

I have been looking for a python implementation that returns a 4- or 8-connected adjacency matrix, given an array. I find it surprising that cv2 or networkx don't include this functionality. I came across this great Matlab [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283732/4663466) and decided to make something similar in python.

**Problem**: I'm looking for an implementation that improves on the linked Matlab solution in runtime / space OR other interesting approaches.

**Disclaimer**:

I submit my own implementation here as I figure I can't be the only person who will ever need to create an (4 / 8 connected) adjacency matrix for image processing or other applications. It is my hope that improvements or better implementations will be offered.

Answer (score 6):

Using the diagonal structure, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283732/4663466) regarding "Construct adjacency matrix in MATLAB", I create only the upper diagonals and add them in the appropriate positions to a sparse diagonal matrix using [scipy.sparse.diags](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html).  This sparse matrix is added to its transpose to give us the adjacency matrix.

When working with images it is often desirable to break up the image into non-overlapping rectangular sub-images or patches.  The patch_size parameter is a tuple (rows, cols) that describes the rectangular patch of size 'rows x cols'.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as s

def connected_adjacency(image, connect, patch_size=(1, 1)):
    """
    Creates an adjacency matrix from an image where nodes are considered adjacent 
    based on 4-connected or 8-connected pixel neighborhoods.

    :param image: 2 or 3 dim array
    :param connect: string, either '4' or '8'
    :param patch_size: tuple (n,m) used if the image will be decomposed into 
                   contiguous, non-overlapping patches of size n x m. The 
                   adjacency matrix will be formed from the smaller sized array
                   e.g. original image size = 256 x 256, patch_size=(8, 8), 
                   then the image under consideration is of size 32 x 32 and 
                   the adjacency matrix will be of size 
                   32**2 x 32**2 = 1024 x 1024
    :return: adjacency matrix as a sparse matrix (type=scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix)
    """

    r, c = image.shape[:2]

    r = r / patch_size[0]
    c = c / patch_size[1]

    if connect == '4':
        # constructed from 2 diagonals above the main diagonal
        d1 = np.tile(np.append(np.ones(c-1), [0]), r)[:-1]
        d2 = np.ones(c*(r-1))
        upper_diags = s.diags([d1, d2], [1, c])
        return upper_diags + upper_diags.T

    elif connect == '8':
        # constructed from 4 diagonals above the main diagonal
        d1 = np.tile(np.append(np.ones(c-1), [0]), r)[:-1]
        d2 = np.append([0], d1[:c*(r-1)])
        d3 = np.ones(c*(r-1))
        d4 = d2[1:-1]
        upper_diags = s.diags([d1, d2, d3, d4], [1, c-1, c, c+1])
        return upper_diags + upper_diags.T
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid parameter \'connect\'={connect}, must be "4" or "8".'
                     .format(connect=repr(connect)))
```

A simple example:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
adj = connected_adjacency(a, '4').toarray()
print a

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

print adj

[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Using networkx + matplotlib to plot the adjacency matrix as a graph:
[image]

Comment: How about showing the code that produces this plot *and* this specific labeling scheme?

Comment: @FaCoffee I believe I used the answer at the bottom of my post on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29574114/4663466.  It uses networkx https://networkx.github.io/