# networkx - Dump graph into JSON with weight

Tags: python, json, networkx

I try to dump the networkx graph into JSON by using [node_link_data](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html). I am able to do that but the link from JSON I got only has target and source.

My question is how do I get weight write to JSON together with the links.

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with how you set weight to an edge. Since you haven't provided any code, here's an example to get you started.

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

G = nx.Graph([(1,2)])
G.add_edge(1,2, weight=5)

json_graph.node_link_data(G)
```

gives output

> {'directed': False,  'graph': {},
>   'links': [{'source': 0, 'target':
>   1, 'weight': 5}],
>   'multigraph': False,  'nodes': [{'id': 1}, {'id':
>   2}]}

As you can see weight is there.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the answer. I was working with csv data like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572623/plot-networkx-graph-from-adjacency-matrix-in-csv-file). But my data is 0 to 1 and I only write edge when the value is more than 0.7.

Comment: I'm not sure if you still have a question. Is it how do I remove edges from a graph with weight <0.7? You can do it with a for loop. Or is it something else?