# Sparse representation of large matrix in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I am trying to plot the adjacency matrix of the [Berkeley-Stanford web graph](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/SNAP/web-BerkStan.html) with related [edge list](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-BerkStan.html) using python. The result should be as in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSj4L.png). My first attempt was to use a dense representation as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

n=685230
matrix = [[0 for i in range(0,n)] for j in range(0,n)]

with open("web-BerkStan.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        li=line.strip()
        if not li.startswith("#"):
            i,j = re.split(r'\t+', li)
            matrix[int(i)][int(j)] = 1


f = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='binary', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

f.savefig('graph.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The code works for, e.g., `n=10` but it is unfeasible for the size of the web graph I am considering, given `n=685230`.

Alternatively, I tried to replace the dense representation with the coordinate format:

```
matrix = []
with open("web-BerkStan.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        li=line.strip()
        if not li.startswith("#"):
            i,j = re.split(r'\t+', li)
            matrix.append([int(i),int(j)])
```

where `matrix` is now an edge list. How do I plot the edge list as a sparse matrix?

Comment: Have you tried using `networkx` python package? Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572623/plot-networkx-graph-from-adjacency-matrix-in-csv-file).

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to follow this [guide](http://sociograph.blogspot.com/2012/11/visualizing-adjacency-matrices-in-python.html) but it is not clear to me how to define a graph in `networkx` starting from an edge list. Also, in the guide it seems that they explicitly define an adjacency matrix which can be too large to store.