# How to import csv format Adjacency Matrix hashtag network in CSV file?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, networkx

My hashtag co-occurrence network is stored as an adjacency matrix in CSV format like this.

```
,#A,#B,#C,#D,#E,#F,#G,#H,#I,#J,#K
#A,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
#B,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
#C,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
...
```

Then I use this page as a reference  [Plot NetworkX Graph from Adjacency Matrix in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572623/plot-networkx-graph-from-adjacency-matrix-in-csv-file)

I want to import this matrix into networkx and I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np

mydata = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
```

But I only got this:

```
print(mydata)
print(type(mydata))

[nan nan]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I import my data correctly, I want to use the python pipeline to calculate degree centrality of each nodes in the network.And importing is the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numpy.genfromtxt` function has an optional argument called comments that by default is set to `"#"`.

```
comments : str, optional
    The character used to indicate the start of a comment.
    All the characters occurring on a line after a comment are discarded
```

In other words numpy thinks your entire file contains comments and empty rows.
You will have to either rename your row and column identifiers or you have to set the comments argument to some other value such as `"*"`

Answer (score 0):

You might find it much simpler to read the `.csv` file into a pandas dataframe, and create a graph from it, including the node names directly with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=',')
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
```

Sample run using the above dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO('''
#A,#B,#C,#D,#E,#F,#G,#H,#I,#J,#K
#A,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
#B,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
#C,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0
''')

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep=',')
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
G.edges()
# EdgeView([('#A', '#B'), ('#A', '#C')])
```

The dataframe has been clipped to the 3rd column, since the dataframe has to be square. But hopefully you see how this way would be quite easier.

Comment: I have tried to read the matrix into a dataframe but there raised an error that I can not understand. KeyError: 'None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1683, step=1)] are in the [columns]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NetworkXError ('Columns must match Indices.', ' My matrix is a 1683x1683 matrix, I guess it may be the df shape is not square

Comment: Are you sure you're csv looks like what you have shared? so as my `s` string? @HelixHerry

Comment: I did not use the StringIO, do I have to use the StringIO to read the csv first?

Comment: That is just to simulate the csv scenario. It acts as if my `s` was your csv file location @helix