# Python: scipy will not upgrade

Tags: python, scipy, networkx

I am trying to upgrade *scipy* to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363860/plot-networkx-graph-with-numpy-array-error). I go to the Command Prompt, type

```
pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy
```

and the output is "Successfully installed scipy-1.9.0". However, if I go to Jupyter and type:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

the output is 1.7.3. Does anybody know what's going on? Total noob here.
Thanks!

Comment: Your Jupyter is using a different Python environment than the one to which you install `scipy`

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @user:1397946is right, you are installing scipy to the wrong python environment. An easy way to install packages in the 'right' environment (i.e. the one used by jupyter) is to use install it directly from inside Jupyter:

```
%pip install scipy
```

By adding the percentage sign in front you can run command line arguments from inside the Jupyter environment ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498226/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclamation-and-question-marks-in-jupyter-notebook)). This way it should install it to the right environment.

Edit: @DominikStańczak is right. The percentage sign is the better option!

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? I thought `!` in Jupyter just passes the command to bash. The way I usually do pip installs from Jupyter is `%pip install`, via the [built-in magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

Comment: You are correct @DominikStańczak . Using the magic commands is now best practice. It will insure it goes to the right environment, which the exclamation point alone won't do. Those interested can see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the `%pip` and `%conda` magic commands now in Jupyter.