# Make two columns CSV file user id displayed once and space-delimited lists of meeting - python

Tags: python, csv

[my question related to this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009615/extract-column-from-csv-file-to-use-as-nodelist-in-networkx/48450018#48450018)

Excellent explanation in the above link. But in my situation is little bit different.

```
user     meetings
178787    287750
178787    151515
178787    158478
576585    896352
576585    985639
576585    456988
```

expected result is

```
user       meetings
178787   "[287750,151515,158478]"
576585   "[896352,985639,456988]"
```

How can i make this done using python with above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `user` is going to be the key, let's stuff a dictionary. Note: this will ultimately load the entire file into memory once, but it does not require the file to be sorted by `user` first. Also note the output is not sorted either (because `dict.items()` does not retrieve dictionary items in any deterministic order).

```
output = {}
with f as open('input.csv'):
    for line in f:
        user, meeting = line.strip('\r\n').split()
        # we strip newlines before splitting on whitespace

        if user not in output and user != 'user': 
            # the user was not found in the dict (and we want to skip the header)
            output[user] = [meeting] # add the user, with the first meeting
        else: # user already exists in dict
            output[user].append(meeting) # add meeting to user entry

# print output header
print("user meetings") # I used a single space, feel free to use '\t' etc.
# lets retrieve all meetings per user
for user, meetings in output.items() # in python2, use .iteritems() instead
    meetings = ','.join(_ for _ in meetings) # format ["1","2","3"] to "1,2,3"
    print('{} "[{}]"'.format(user, meetings))
```

Fancier: sort output. I do this by sorting the keys first. Note that this will use even more memory since I am creating a list of the keys too.

```
# same as before
output = {}
with f as open('input.csv'):
for line in f:
    user, meeting = line.strip('\r\n').split()
    # we strip newlines before splitting on whitespace

    if user not in output and user != 'user': 
        # the user was not found in the dict (and we want to skip the header)
        output[user] = [meeting] # add the user, with the first meeting
    else: # user already exists in dict
        output[user].append(meeting) # add meeting to user entry

# print output header
print("user meetings") # I used a single space, feel free to use '\t' etc.

# sort my dict keys before printing them:
for user in sorted(output.keys()):
    meetings = ','.join(_ for _ in output[user])
    print('{} "[{}]"'.format(user, meetings))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could read in the file, line by line, `split` the lines and add the `meeting` to a `dictionary` where the key is the `user`. This can be done very neatly using the method [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905999/python-dict-how-to-create-key-or-append-an-element-to-key).

We can then write this dictionary back to the same file using `tabs` to make everything line up.

So, assuming your file is called `f.csv`, the code would look something like:

```
d = {}
for l in open('f.csv').read().split('\n')[1:-1]:
    u, m = l.split()
    d.setdefault(u, []).append(m)

with open('f.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('user\tmeetings\n')
    for u, m in d.items():
        f.write(u + '\t' + str(m) + '\n')
```

---

Which produces the desired output of:

```
user    meetings
178787  ['287750', '151515', '158478']
576585  ['896352', '985639', '456988']
```

Comment: I like the use of `dict.setdefault()` here

Comment: @cowbert Yeah, it's a cool use

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

inpath = ''  # Path to input CSV file
outpath = ''  # Path to output CSV file

output = defaultdict(list)  # Dictionary like {user_id: [meetings]}

for row in csv.DictReader(open(inpath)):
    output[row['user']].append(row['meetings'])

with open(outpath, 'w') as f:
    for user, meetings in output.items():
        row = user + ',' + str(meetings) + '\n'
        f.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) provides a nice solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', columns=['user', 'meetings'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('user')['meetings'].apply(list).astype(str).reset_index()
```

Comment: Amazing Thank you jp_data_analysis its worked perfectly.